# Django: URLField model field exceptions

Tags: python, django, django-models, exception

I've a model called `urls` (see below), how to handle some sort of `link does not exists` exception if I set `verify_exists = True`?

If the given link does not exist then this form is being invalid.

```
class Urls(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    link = models.URLField(verify_exists = True, verbose_name = u'URI')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title + ': ' + self.link
```

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to overwrite the clean() method for that particular field in the form

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/